# Migrating Roles from one environment to another

Tags: user-roles

I have 2 identical environments . Now, on one I have created many roles and have assigned users to them . How do I migrate this to the other server which has the same set of users already.

Any suggestions to the problem would be great.

Comment: is a complete database migration not an option? I suggest exporting/importing the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables.

Comment: The roles themselves live in the wp_options table: `SELECT * FROM wp_options where option_name = 'wp_user_roles';`

Comment: Thanks Eric and Rup , I will try to Migrate just the WP_user_Roles and post the results here today. Hope all  goes well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I Migrated the contents of `meta_Key` `'wp_user_roles'` from the `wp_options` table from one server to another after a backup and it worked , the Roles migration was successful.